# Segmentation fault in a massively recursive function

Tags: c++, math

I have a function that calls itself a near infinite amount of times, but it does have an end. It calculates the mathematical formula (in TeX):

When `x<a`:

```
g_{a}(x)=1
```

When `x>=a`:

```
g_{a}(x)=g_{a}(x-1)+g_a(x-a)
```

Here is my code(c++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double g( double a, double x){
    if (x>=a) return (g(a,x-1)+g(a,x-a));
    else if (x<a) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main(){cout << g(sqrt(10000019),10000019);}
```

I call the function with `g(sqrt(10000019),10000019);`
How do I stop the SEGFAULT?

Comment: With what values of a and x are you getting the SEGFAULT?

Comment: And also, can't you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: BTW it is Ackermann_function, am I correct?? if yes then I doubt you can stop SEGFAULT.

Comment: @Adel Edited with call

Comment: @Fabio Is it not a MCVE?

Comment: @Lightness erm... no? When I say near infinite, I sorta meant its overflowing my stack.

Comment: @KaidenPrince see if this makes sense ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742322/how-to-rewrite-ackermann-function-in-non-recursive-style

Comment: @KaidenPrince The function is complete, but a real MCVE also includes the `main()` function, and the #included headers, and so on. So that we can copy it, paste it into an IDE (even an online one), and see the error. By the way, including `main()` is important because then we can see the call to the function that is leading to your problem. At the beginning you hadn't included it... Now we have everything (I think), but we still have to put all the pieces together. If **you** did that,we would be able to focus directly on the problem.

Comment: @FabioTurati Better?

Comment: @GautamJha Brain overload... I am not a very good programmer...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your seg-fault was from running out of stack space.

You can limit/unlimit how big your stack space is (on Linux at least)
using the limit command from tcsh.

```
 % limit 
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    10240 kbytes
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  4096 
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024
```

You can then unlimit your stacksize

```
% unlimit stacksize
% limit

cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    unlimited
coredumpsize 0 kbytes
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  4096 
memorylocked 64 kbytes
maxproc      1024
```

And give it another try.

Comment: It's still going to crash when it runs out of memory--

Comment: Yes, but he may make it far enough for his purposes.  Another solution would to cache/memoize small values so it doesn't ave to do as much recursion.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a function that calls itself a near infinite amount of times, but it does have an end.

Do you have a near infinite amount of stack memory?

If not (the likely scenario), you are going to smash your stack in no time. A segmentation fault is a clear sign of that here.

I'd avoid the recursion altogether.

Comment: How would I convert this to iteration then?

Comment: @KaidenPrince: With your fingers...? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't really know how to convert it, or else I would of.

Comment: You can also try converting it into tail recursion.  Then the optimizer will hit it and turn it into iteration for you.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Will try. Post an update later. GCC will optimize this?

Comment: @KaidenPrince - it should optimize *tail* recursion.  This means that no operation can happen after the recursive call.  The addition you do in your return statement is such an operation.  Converting to tail recursion often involves passing the result as an accumulator parameter into the recursive call.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537432/convert-recursion-to-tail-recursion

Comment: I seem unable to understand how to convert this to tail recursion.