# I don't know how to correct my tail recursion (originally regular recursion)

Tags: c, recursion, tail-recursion

I was assigned funct() and was told to convert it into tail recursion, so I made funct2(). I used another stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) to begin and it kind of works, but it's always a value off.

I *think* the problem is due to the **y** value being 0 initially, and when going to the **else** part of the function, subtracts from **0** rather than a value that is equivalent to the initial **x**. But I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int funct(int x);
int funct2(int x, int y);

int main() {

    int x = 24;

    printf("%d %d", funct(x), funct2(x, 0));


}

int funct(int x) {

    if (x <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x & 0x01){
        return x + funct(x-1);
    }
    else {
        return x - funct(x-1);
    }

}

int funct2(int x, int y) {

    if (x < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x == 0){
        return y;
    }
    else if (x & 0x01){
        return funct2(x-1, y+x);
    }
    else {
        return funct2(x-1, y-(x-1));
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: tail recursion isn't a language level feature of C, so if you compiler does something fancy to not increase the stack level for the tail calls... that would be a specific optimization... unless you write it with goto and labels ... which are C level constructs, evil, evil constructs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15540236/3403834). Since your recursive step is not associative, you cannot achieve tail recursion with just two arguments. Consider passing three:

```
    int tailrec(int x, int k, int acc)
    {
        if (x < 0) {
            return acc;
        }
        if (k & 0x01) {
            return tailrec(x - 1, k + 1, k + acc);
        } else {
            return tailrec(x - 1, k + 1, k - acc);
        }
    }
```